# Issue with bulk operations in Flask-SQLAlchemy. Could not locate a bind configured(...)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make my update db quicker that's why I want to use bulk operations. I've a TEST table witch contains around 200k rows. Every day I've to clean the table and load fresh data. When I do this one by one it takes my 2 hours.

I'd like put all the data into dictionary and insert in one operations.

I use a code like below but something is wrong. Do You know what should I change ?

> sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind
>   configured on mapper Mapper|TEST|TEST or this Session

my db table:

```
class TEST(db.Model):
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    PN = db.Column(db.String(45))
    AMOUNT = db.Column(db.String(6))
```

and insert code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, Session
s=Session()

s.bulk_insert_mappings(TEST,
  [dict(PN='TEST2', AMOUNT=200), dict(PN='TEST3', AMOUNT=300), dict(PN='TEST5', AMOUNT=500)]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to import Session from flask_sqlalchemy.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import Session
```

And if you configure flask-sqlalchemy correctly `flask_sqlalchemy` internally configured below mess in behind the scene.

---

`When do I make a sessionmaker?`

You are importing the Session wrong way. You have to bind it to the create_engine

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, Session
engine = create_engine('sqlite3://...')
s = Session(bind=engine)
```